# What is the best way to secure your backend code with SSL?

Tags: facebook, spring-boot, ssl, oauth-2.0

I am newbie here. Trying to set up an end to end service running.

Here is my scenario:

1. frontend is hosted in heroku.
2. backend is spring-boot and server is hosted in AWS.

My backend service has integrated the facebook Oauth2 login, for which I must provide a redirect URL which is https. To handle that I created a self signed certificate and secured my backend service with the same.

Everything is working fine till here except the security warning users will get in the browser as the certificate is self signed. AFAIK I must get a CA root certificate to avoid this. but to get the CA root certificate i need to provide the domain i will be protecting. For the backend server there is no domain, it will just be a static ip.

Can someone please guide me as to what is the correct approach here ?

Comment: SSL certificates _can_ be issued for IP addresses - but I don’t know if any of the major, trusted registries does offer that. You might simply have to _get_ a domain for your backend. (Or add an additional subdomain for a domain you already have maybe, if you don’t want to spend money on getting an extra one.)

Comment: Thanks, we do have a domain for our website, can i use that and get the cert, and then use the same cert to secure backend servers, irrespective of the IP they run on. I don't know how they check the authenticity of domains and can i use the same cert to secure backend service or not.

Comment: _“and can i use the same cert to secure backend service or not”_ - well that depends on whether the certificate covers the domain names you use to access your backend, or not.

Comment: @misorude "but I don’t know if any of the major, trusted registries" 1) CAs, not registries, and 2) some do, like: https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1216536-securing-a-public-ip-address---ssl-certificates   However it is mostly not a good idea to use HTTPS URLs with IP addresses instead of hostnames.

Comment: Thanks @misorude for helping me out here :)